# .NET Core: How to change authentication based on URL structure?

Tags: azure, authentication, web-applications, .net-core, legacy

I have created a NET Core web app for my company utilizing single-tenant Azure AD authentication. The app is an administrative tool for setting variables used by other (legacy) applications. The root url is like `"https://mycompanyadmintool.azurewebsites.net"`. It works very well.

Now I have been asked to add what we can call "legacy authentication" to the app. This is a temporary solution and will hopefully be discarded soon. Basically this means that when the application is called with a url like this: `"https://mycompanyadmintool.azurewebsites.net/<some Guid or string or number or whatever>"`, the Azure AD login should be bypassed. Then the last part of the URL will be verified and the authentication succeeds or not.

No matter what I try, I can not bypass the Azure AD authentication (except from disabling it totally!) and make this work without a lot of hacks and cheap tricks (lots of bad code).

I am fairly new to .NET Core and middleware +++ and need some guidance here. I have tried to look into the MVC routing, have a feeling that a part of the solution might have something to do with routing.

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to do it the "right" way? Grateful for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to open a separate branch in the request pipeline with a separate authentication. This should work using the app.Map or app.MapWhen methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware

```
app.Map("/subpath", sub_app=> {
     sub_app.UseWhateverAuth(); // <= custom auth
     // ...
     sub_app.UseWhateverMiddleware();
     sub_app.UseMvc();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that documentation. I was not aware of "app.Map" - seems promising.

I will try this out and get back with the result.